# Does the metric defined by d/(1+d) preserve open sets

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Given a metric d, I showed that d/(1+d) is a metric. Now I want to verify whether it preserves open sets. If a set U is open in (X,d), then is it open in (X,d')? Let $x \in U$, let r>0 such that $B(x,r)\subset U$. I tried letting r'=r/(1+r) and r'=r(1-r) as well as a few other likely candidates, But I can't show that in general openness is conserved. However, I also can't find a counter example.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let $B(x,r) := \{y\in X:\ d(y,x) < r\}$ and $B'(x,\rho) := \{y\in X:\ \varphi(d(y,x)) < \rho\}$,
where $\varphi(t) := t/(1+t)$, $t\geq 0$.

It is enough to show that, for every $x\in X$ and $r>0$, there exists $\rho > 0$
such that $B(x,r) \supset B'(x,\rho)$ and viceversa.

One inclusion follows immediately observing that
$B(x,r) = B'(x, \varphi(r))$.

The other inclusion follows observing that $\varphi$ is an increasing bijection between $[0,+\infty)$ and $[0,1)$, so that
$$
B'(x,\rho) =
\begin{cases}
B(x, \rho(1-\rho)), &\text{if}\ \rho\in [0,1),\\
X, &\text{if}\ \rho \geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first inclusion. If $d(x,y) < r$, why must $d'(x,y)$ be less than $r/(1+r)$

Comment: Because the function $\varphi$ is (strictly) increasing.

Comment: I realize that this is a criterion for equivalence of metrics, but I am not too familiar with the concept. Say I am given a set U which is open in (X,d'), then clearly it is open in  (X,d) because of the first inclusion. However, if I take a set U which is open in (X,d), the second inclusion tells me that for any r>0, i can find r' such that B'(x,r) is in B(x,r'), but how does it guarantee that such an B(x,r') will be in U?

Comment: Given $B(x,r) \subset U$, you can find $\rho>0$ such that $B'(x,\rho) \subset B(x,r)$.